# JQuery, javascript slideToggle()

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidetoggle

I'm trying to make a script that collapses and expands when you either press the text or the image. The images is a basic arrow, which is being replaced by an arrow pointing upwards when the `div` is expanded.

My problem is that the text disappears when I toggle the div. How should I write my code, so the headline would stay, no matter if the `div` is expanded or not? I would like to use the following script on several `div`s.

Furthermore the slideToggle() function does not work both ways, how do I solve this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function toggle(divId, switchImgTag) {
            var ele = document.getElementById(divId);
            var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
            $("#" + divId).slideToggle("fast");
            if (ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="images/arrow_down.png">';
            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                imageEle.innerHTML = '<img src="images/arrow_up.png">';                    
            }
        }
    </script>
```

And the HTML:

```
<a id='imageDivLink' href="javascript:toggle('skills', 'imageDivLink');">
     <h2>Skills And Expertise</h2>
     <img class='arrow' src='images/arrow_down.png'>
</a>
<div id='skills' style='display:none;'>
     Lorem Ipsum...
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
function toggle(divId, switchImgTag) {
    var ele = $("#" + divId);
    var imageEle = $('#' + switchImgTag).find('img');
    if (ele.is(':visible')) {
        imageEle.attr('src', "images/arrow_down.png");
    } else {
        imageEle.attr('src', "images/arrow_up.png");
    }
    $("#" + divId).slideToggle("fast");
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XHTeS/)

Answer (score 0):

Problem is - you're using `innerHTML` it replaces all of your element HTML, to avoid it use `append()`;

Answer (score 0):

First of all $("#" + divId).slideToggle("fast"); in your case is useless, since you do the toggle manually using simple jquery right after it. Read http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ and after you understand it you can just remove everything from that point on.

Also use the "complete" callback to add your "personal touches" at the end of animation.

Your function should look like this:

```
    function toggle(divId, switchImgTag) {
        var ele = document.getElementById(divId);
        var imageEle = document.getElementById(switchImgTag);
        $("#" + divId).slideToggle('fast', function() {
          // Change icon.
          // Change text.
        });
    }
```

About the text, you can change it the same way you currently change image.

Answer (score 0):

**`innerHTML`** replace the whole element(**affects it child elements**).

So work on the `img` tag like below

```
if (ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";
                $('.arrow').prop('src', 'images/arrow_down.png'); //change like

            }
            else {
                ele.style.display = "block";
                $('.arrow').prop('src', 'images/arrow_up.png');  //change like             
            }
```